# MVC 5 model inside model back to controller

Tags: razor, model, controller, asp.net-mvc-5

I have a model where inside I have 2 models :

```
public class ASayfa
    {
        public UArama u = new UArama();
        public HArama h = new HArama();
    }
```

The classes inside ASayfa is as follow :

```
 public class UArama
    {
        public string ad { get; set; }
        public bool varmi { get; set; }
    }
public class HArama
        {
            public string hazir { get; set; }
            public bool varmi { get; set; }
        }
```

In my view :

```
 @using (Html.BeginForm("uArama", "Home"))
    {
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.u.ad, new { @class = "suggestBox ui-autocomplete-input", id = "ad", autocomplete = "off" })

   <input type="submit" value=@Resources.UAramaTus class="search-btn" onclick="">
}
```

When I submit the form , the model is empty. Before I had just the UArama class and it was working , but when I change it to be inside ASayfa class it started to come back empty.
How can I make this work ? I need to use two models in a single view as there will a secondary hml.beginform with its own submit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution.
 In the main class :

```
public class ASayfa
    {
        public UArama u = new UArama();
        public HArama h = new HArama();
    }
```

changed it to :

```
public class ASayfa
        {
            public UArama u {get; set;}
            public HArama h {get; set;}
        }
```

and it worked

Comment: Just what I needed. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

One solution would be to create an `EditorTemplate` for each of the sub-types, `UArama u` and `HArama h`

An editor-template is a .cshtml (or .aspx) file that is set up to handle any model-instance of a particular type.

By ASP.Net-MVC's convention, editor templates are placed in `/Views/Shared/EditorTemplates`. An  editor template with a model-type `@model mynamespace.UArama` placed in this location will then, by default, be used when you call:

```
@Html.EditorFor(m => m.u)
```

I have found that model binding works well when I use editor templates this way.